# How to monitor http requests on an android phone?

Tags: android, http, request, remote-debugging, traffic

There are many questions to this but most of the answers are outdated and don't work for me.

How can I monitor http requests made by an app in my android phone? It doesn't matter if I proxy the traffic through my pc or view the requests directly on my phone.